# HTML5 offline capabilities in a sub directory

Tags: ipad, html, mobile, offline

I'm trying to setup a iPad app to work offline.  I was able to successfully get it to work but I was told to put the app in multiple sub directories.  When I did this and update the cache manifest file to the new destinations of all the files I kept getting an error that the site wouldn't work because it wasn't connected to the internet.  I tried multiple paths and looked up different ideas but have come up empty handed.  Is their a way to get offline mode working with a site inside sub directories?

Thanks.

Comment: did you 1: add the subdirs to the manifest, 2: set the mime-type of the manifest-file?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't make a difference. Make sure all urls in the manifest are relative and always end the manifest with:

```
NETWORK:
*
```

Furthermore make sure you don't forget to add any images, libraries etc. from the cached url's to the manifest. Sometimes even caps can make a difference. OPen the console of the developer tools in Chrome to see what's being cached and what breaks loading the appcache.

Also make sure there are no iframes (ie. like-buttons) on the homepage(page that includes the manifest attribute in the html-tag) which is **always** cached.

**Little trick:**
If you want to fallback you're homepage place the manifest attribute in an invisible iframe on the homepage of your app.
That way you have total control over what's cached and what not.